# How to get the middle part of the activity to be scrollable?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I am trying to get something like this in one of my activities:

[attraction detailed view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIwFm.png)

I want the image to be fixed at the top, the middle bit with the text to be scrollable as description and short description will have quite a lot of text, and the buttons to be fixed to the bottom. only the middle one is permanent visibility, the margin ones are hidden or visible depending type of attraction listed.

I tried to enclose in linear layouts but didnt work, most probably my mistake.

**My xml file is :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    tools:context=".DetailedViewActivity">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewDetailedName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/share_bold"
    android:text="@string/name"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/colorDark"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView4" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewDetailedAddress"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/share"
    android:text="@string/address"
    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
    android:textColor="@color/colorDark"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textViewDetailedInfoAddress"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textViewDetailedInfoAddress"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewDetailedInfoAddress" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewDetailedPostCode"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/share"
    android:text="@string/post_code"
    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
    android:textColor="@color/colorDark"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textViewDetailedInfoPostCode"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textViewDetailedInfoPostCode"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewDetailedInfoPostCode" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewDetailedShortDesc"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/share"
    android:text="@string/short_description"
    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
    android:textColor="@color/colorDark"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textViewDetailedInfoShortDesc"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textViewDetailedInfoShortDesc"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewDetailedInfoShortDesc" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewDetailedDesc"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/share"
    android:text="@string/description"
    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
    android:textColor="@color/colorDark"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textViewDetailedName"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textViewDetailedName"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewDetailedInfoDescription" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewDetailedPrice"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/share"
    android:text="@string/price"
    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
    android:textColor="@color/colorDark"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textViewDetailedName"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textViewDetailedName"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewDetailedInfoPrice" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewDetailedInfoAddress"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/share"
    android:text="@string/address"
    android:textColor="@color/colorTeal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textViewDetailedName"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textViewDetailedName"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewDetailedName" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewDetailedInfoPostCode"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/share"
    android:text="@string/post_code"
    android:textColor="@color/colorTeal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textViewDetailedAddress"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textViewDetailedAddress"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewDetailedAddress" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewDetailedInfoShortDesc"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/share"
    android:text="@string/short_description"
    android:textColor="@color/colorTeal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textViewDetailedPostCode"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textViewDetailedPostCode"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewDetailedPostCode" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewDetailedInfoDescription"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/share"
    android:text="@string/description"
    android:textColor="@color/colorTeal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textViewDetailedShortDesc"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textViewDetailedShortDesc"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewDetailedShortDesc" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewDetailedInfoPrice"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/share"
    android:text="@string/price"
    android:textColor="@color/colorTeal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textViewDetailedDesc"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textViewDetailedDesc"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewDetailedDesc" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="270dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_image" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnReadReviews"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/share_bold"
    android:text="@string/read_reviews"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="@color/colorDark"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:cornerRadius="7dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnBook"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/share_bold"
    android:text="@string/book"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="@color/colorDark"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:cornerRadius="7dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnPostReview"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/share_bold"
    android:text="@string/add_review"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="@color/colorDark"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:cornerRadius="7dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap all scroll views into ScroolView and use another ConstraintLayout inside the ScroolView. You can found an example [here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Working-with-the-ScrollView)